# running function based on user input in C# console application

Tags: c#, console-application

I'm trying to run a console application that will allow a user to pick which type of job they would like to run on their PC and their response will translate to which functions the program runs. The way it is written right now the program will lock up and not allow anything else when the user inputs any options other than 4 which will successfully close the program.

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int userInput = 0;

            DisplayMenu();

            do
            {
                if (userInput == 1)
                {
                    QuickClean();
                }
                else if (userInput == 2)
                {
                    DeepClean();
                }
                else if (userInput == 3)
                {
                    SuperClean();
                }
            } while (userInput != 4);              

        }

        static public int DisplayMenu()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("1. Quick Clean");
            Console.WriteLine("2. Deep Clean");
            Console.WriteLine("3. Super Clean (admin needed)");
            Console.WriteLine("4. exit");
            var result = Console.ReadLine();
            return Convert.ToInt32(result);
        }

        static void QuickClean()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("quickclean");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static void DeepClean()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("deepclean");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static void SuperClean()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("superclean");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

Comment: Move the call to DisplayMenu inside the loop at the first line after the _do_

Comment: When I do this it allows the application to continue and select another option but doesn't write the text as indicated in each write line of quick, deep, and super clean.

Comment: @mcavanaugh418 - It doesn't seem to lock up. Can you explain what you mean?

Comment: @enigmativity the answer below from steve actually resolved the issue.

Comment: @mcavanaugh418 - Ah, got it. It's not locking up, just looping because the use input wasn't asked for again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The DisplayMenu method returns what your user chooses but you don't assign this return to your *usermenu* local variable.

As you have written it now, you ask for input just one time and then enter the loop without setting the local variable *usermenu* to the user choice so it is still zero when it reaches the while to test the exit condition and the loop enters the infinite condition.

You need to move the call to *DisplayMenu* inside the loop and assign the return value to *usermenu*, so your user can see again the menu and input a different choice and you can perform the required operations.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int userInput = 0;
    do
    {
        userInput = DisplayMenu();
        if (userInput == 1)
        {
            QuickClean();
        }
        ....
    } while(userInput != 4)
}
```

I suggest also to change the code in DisplayMenu and avoid to use Convert.ToInt32 to parse the user input. If the user doesn't type a number the Convert.ToInt32 will crash your program. Instead use Int32.TryParse

```
    static public int DisplayMenu()
    {
        Console.Clear();
        while(true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("1. Quick Clean");
            Console.WriteLine("2. Deep Clean");
            Console.WriteLine("3. Super Clean (admin needed)");
            Console.WriteLine("4. exit");
            int result;
            if(Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out result))
                return result;
            else
                Console.WriteLine("Please enter a number");
        }
     }
```

Comment: This works but it has a minor problem. It seems when I select one it calls quickclean and writes the text just fine but I can't select any other option the next time. If I hit 1 it displays quickclean, if I hit 1 again it just displays the menu again instead of quickclean a second time. Maybe this is confusing?

Comment: Nevermind.  i figured this out. It is because i added the console.readline(); to pause the program while testing. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You are not storing the returned value anywhere. `userInput` is still 0 after `DisplayMenu()` is called, that's why you get into an infite loop at the `do-while`.

```
do{
    int userInput = DisplayMenu();
    [...]
} while (userInput != 4)
```